# Change text button in top right in MaterialDatePicker dateRangePicker()

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android, materialdatepicker

[image: screenshot]

I want to change the text button **SAVE** in the top right.
I've used this library

> com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0

```
val dateRangePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    .setTitleText("Select Date")
    .setTheme(R.style.Widget_AppTheme_MaterialDatePicker)
    .build()

dateRangePicker.show(childFragmentManager, "date_range_picker")
dateRangePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
    val start = it.first
    val last = it.second

    if (start != null && last != null){
        val dateRange = "${globalHelper?.convertLongToString(start)} - ${globalHelper?.convertLongToString(last)}"
        binding.tvDateRange.text = dateRange
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding following lines with you own text in strings.xml

```
<string name="mtrl_picker_save" description="Button text to indicate that the widget will save the user's selection [CHAR_LIMIT=16]">.....</string>
<string name="mtrl_picker_cancel" description="Button text to indicate that the widget will ignore the user's selection [CHAR_LIMIT=16]" translatable="false">...</string>
```

Comment: and how to connect between logic and strings.xml?

Comment: This will override the text throughout your app for all datepickers, currently there is no way to set button text for specific datepicker

Comment: I have tried it, did not work for me :( @Harshit Rastogi

Comment: try changing string name to 'mtrl_picker_confirm' instead of 'mtrl_picker_save'

Comment: On emulators everything works fine, however on a real Samsung it doesn't work. Does anyone have any clue?